# Cherrypy server run a python script

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, cherrypy

I want when I press a button in cherrypy a specific python script is executed I tried to add it like that but of course that doesn't work, What is the right way to do it
   What I want to execute is (ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
   ser.write(b'hello') )

```
import cherrypy
import string

class HelloWorld:

    """ Sample request handler class. """
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
       return """<html>
          <head></head>
          <body>
            <form method="get" action="generate">
              <button type="submit">Press!</button>
            </form>
          </body>
          ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
          ser.write(b'hello') 
        </html>"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
   cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0'} )
   cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to dd your code before the `return` outside the string:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def index(self):
   ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
   ser.write(b'hello') 
   return """<html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <form method="get" action="generate">
          <button type="submit">Press!</button>
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>"""
```

This will send `hello` to the serial port. If you want to do it on the button click it has to go into a method called `generate` but is similar to `index` above.

Comment: Thanks ,but When I did that and I press it sure works but it transfer to a new page ....../generate and it is 404 not found ofcourse how to avoid that ?

Comment: As I noted above, you have to write an additional method name `generate` to work on the button click. Then you should move the two lines of code there. At the moment opening index will send the string to the serial port.